You don't have permission to access this resource 403 error on Laravel using docker
I'm trying to configure a laravel app with docker  but when I try to access I get a 403 error

You don't have permission to access this resource.

this is the Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.1 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql zip

RUN echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 9003

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html

COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

this is the docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: "develop,debug"
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "client_host=host.docker.internal start_with_request=yes"
    container_name: myapp_api_webserver_and_php

  mysql:
    image: 'mariadb:10.6'
    container_name: myapp_api_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
    ports:
      - '8003:3306'

and this is apache-config.conf file
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Do I missed something in the configuration?I have to set  something else on the web server permissions?

Where is your index.php file? Showing the entire project invoked by the server is not the safest solution.
Try adding directory 'public' with 'index.php' file.
Mount it via './public:/var/www/html'

index.php file is in/var/www/html/public

Try add localy 'public' directory with 'index.php' and mounting it. I did it and i can see PHP code result.

In short, you must have an index.html, index.php file that will be in the mounted location

doesn't work with './public:/var/www/html'

Do you have your code structures correctly? I did example for you: https://github.com/Mariusz225/stackoverflow/tree/main/78459918

yes ,the struture is correct
